# Proving a function is constant zero with an inequality on its value, first & second order derivative

Tags: analysis, derivatives, inequality

The question goes as follows:

> Suppose $f: (a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$ is twice-differentiable on $(a, b)$, and suppose that
> $$
> |f''\left( x \right) |\le |f'\left( x \right) |+|f\left( x \right) |
> $$
> for all $x\in (a,b)$.
>
> Suppose there exists an $x_0\in (a,b)$ such that $f(x_0) = f'(x_0) = 0$.
>
> Prove that $f(x) \equiv 0$ for all $x \in (a,b)$.

I tried using the *trick* below:

$$
\begin{align}
    \displaystyle \frac{f'\left( x_0+\delta \right) ^2}{2}&=\int_{x_0}^{x_0+\delta}{f'f''dx} \\
    &\le \int_{x_0}^{x_0+\delta}{ff'dx}+\int_{x_0}^{x_0+\delta}{\left( f' \right) ^2dx} \\
    &=\frac{f\left( x_0+\delta \right) ^2}{2}+\delta \cdot f'\left( x_0+\delta \right) ^2 \\
    &\le f'\left( x_0+\delta \right) ^2\cdot \left( \frac{\delta ^2}{2}+\delta \right), 
\end{align}
$$
which is impossible when $\delta \to 0$ if $f'(x_0+\delta)\neq 0$. However, as one can see, there are too many restrictions imposed.

The hint says that one should first prove $f(x)\equiv 0 \,\,(\forall x\in (a,b), |x-x_0|<\frac 12)$, and then prove that $\forall k\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}, |f''(x)|\leq \alpha (1+|x-x_0|)^k\cdot |x-x_0|^k$, where $\alpha := \max\limits_{x\in (a,b)} |f'(x)| +\max\limits_{x\in (a,b)}|f(x)|$. But I can't understand this hint.

Comment: This has been asked and answered before: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1076185/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/251579/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3984521/42969 – all found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%7Cf%27%27%5Cleft(%20x%20%5Cright)%20%7C%5Cle%20%7Cf%27%5Cleft(%20x%20%5Cright)%20%7C%2B%7Cf%5Cleft(%20x%20%5Cright)%20%7C%24)